# HSSF. Clear the cell

Tags: java, apache-poi, poi-hssf, hssf

`sheet.setColumnWidth(13,(short)0);` totally different

`row.removeCell(13);` doesn't work too.

What I should use for this goal?(delete cell)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to clear the data of a cell:

**Option 1:** set the cell's value to `null`. The advantage of this option is you don't need to get the cell style, alignment, font style, etc. for that cell.

```
row.getCell(13).setCellValue(null); 
Cell cell13 = cell.getCell(13);
```

**Option 2:** remove cell. When you take `cell13` again, it will return `null`. That's why you need to create the cell and also the style.

```
 row.removeCell(13);
 Cell cell13 = cell.getCell(13);
```

Comment: Your first option does not work as compiler says there are multiple ambiguous methods for .setCellValue(null) can be a date or boolean etc.